# Strange "syntax error at or near '201112100000'" in PostgreSQL with ODBC

Tags: .net, sql, postgresql, odbc

I am running this query

```
select * from measTbl  where dateone>'201112100000' and dateone<'202001010000' and netcd<>99
```

in a 32bit c# MVC application running on win7 64bit against a PostgresSQL server, using the  32bit ODBC driver psqlODBC 9.00.0310. I always get this error:

```
ERROR [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "201112100000";
Error while executing the query
```

the .net code I use is this

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CSPOSTGRES"].ToString(); ;
OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand();
comm.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
var strData= System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(double)giorni).ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"0000";
var commandText=String.Format ("select * from measTbl  where dateone  >'{0}' and dateone<'202001010000' and netcd<>99", strData);
comm.CommandText = strData;

OdbcDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
```

The strangest thing is that if I use a winforms 64bit app with the 64 bit driver, the same query works perfectly.

I must use the 32bit in production, so using the 64bit is not an option.

any ideas?
thanks.

Comment: What is the field type of dateone? Please post sample code.

Comment: dateone is a  varchar holding dates. (my database explorer in vs2010 tells me varchar, I do not know if this is the right name for the variable char type in PostgreSQL).

Comment: using something like `'201112100000'` as a comparison agains a real `date` column is not a good idea. You should use `DATE '2011-12-10'` or `to_date('20111210','yyyyMMdd')` instead.

Comment: When executing this query with the command line interface, do you get the same msg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `strData` to the CommandText property and that is the first problem.

```
var commandText=String.Format ("select * from measTbl  where dateone  >'{0}' and dateone<'202001010000' and netcd<>99",
                    strData);
comm.CommandText = commandText;
```

Another problem is that you are `comparing` strings (as you said that field datatype of dateone is varchar). It is better to convert dateone field value to date if any function in psql.

PS: Try to use parameterized sql statement to avoid such sql injection and complex concatenation.

For instance,

```
cmd.CommandText="select * from measTbl where (dateone>@date1 and dateone<@date2) 
                        and netcd<>@netcd";
```

I'm not sure what parameter symbol (@, ? or :) is used with PSQL and ODBC.